# Directly access older MDB files

Tags: c++, ms-access, mfc, odbc

I have a C++ (MFC) application. My customer needs me to add a feature to read from some data files.

These data files are MDB files. They appear to be for older versions of Microsoft Access (probably versions prior to the year 2007, but I haven't been able to confirm that).

I'm up for reading these files directly if I can find sufficient documentation on their format. I'm also up to hearing about older ODBC or other similar tools that would work with these older files. But a requirement is that we don't need to install a bunch of additional software. Ideally, I can do this all from C++.

Could I get some suggestions on how I might access this data? Where is the format documents and what might be some other options than reading it directly myself?

*Note: [This article](https://xiph.org/positron/doc/mdb.html) presents the layout of an MDB file; however, it does not seem to match the content of the files I'm working with.*

Comment: are you able to successfully connect to this DB from Visual Studio? (`Tools--> Connect To Database`) If so, it could be a good indication that drivers are available for this (old) format.

Comment: Absolutely not. Although Access is installed on my computer, I don't have any software on my system that is capable of reading these old MDB files.

Comment: ouch! not even Access???

Comment: I have Access 2013. It won't read these old files. And, as indicated, our preference is to read the file without Access or any other software. All I need is some good documentation of the format.

Comment: The Access 2010 runtime is freely available at https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=10910, this might work for you.

Comment: @beerboy: Thanks, but it appears that 1) the MDB files I have require an older version of Access than 2010, and 2) that download is unsupported on Windows 10?

Comment: *I'm also up to hearing about older ODBC or other similar tools that would work with these older files*. Basically, I think you will need to install the [Jet 3.51 OLE DB Provider](http://download.cnet.com/Microsoft-Jet-Database-Engine-3-5/3000-18493_4-10052770.html) which can read Access 97 mdb files, then set the appropriate connection string and work with oledb. This should be much easier than to parse the file, that IF you manage to find the full documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use `CDatabase` with the Microsoft Jet driver to connect to MDB databases.

I locate the correct driver like this:

```
// We now iterate the JET drivers list and locate a valid MDB driver
CString CPTSDatabase::GetJETDriver(bool bAccDbMode)
{
    CString         strDriver;
    CString         strName, strNameLower, strValue;
    CString         strDefaultDriver = _T("Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)");
    CString         strDBType = _T("(*.mdb)");
    CStringArray    aryStrDrivers;
    TCHAR           szBuf[2001];
    WORD            cbBufMax = 2000;
    WORD            cbBufOut;
    TCHAR           *pszBuf = szBuf;

    if (SQLGetInstalledDrivers(szBuf, cbBufMax, &cbBufOut))
    {
#ifdef _WIN64
        strDefaultDriver = _T("Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)");
        strDBType = _T("(*.mdb, *.accdb)");
#else
        if (bAccDbMode)
        {
            strDefaultDriver = _T("Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)");
            strDBType = _T("(*.mdb, *.accdb)");
        }
#endif
        do 
        {
            strName = CString(pszBuf);
            strNameLower = strName;
            strNameLower.MakeLower();

            if (strNameLower.Find(strDBType) != -1)
            {
                aryStrDrivers.Add(strName);
                if (strName.CollateNoCase(strDefaultDriver) == 0)
                {
                    strDriver = strName;
                    break;
                }
            }

            pszBuf = _tcschr(pszBuf, _T('\0')) + 1;
        } while (pszBuf[1] != _T('\0'));

        if (strDriver.IsEmpty() && aryStrDrivers.GetSize() > 0)
        {
            // Try and use the first MDB driver we found
            strDriver = aryStrDrivers.GetAt(0);
        }
    }

    // Make a note of the driver
    AfxGetApp()->WriteProfileString(_T("Options"), _T("JET Connection Driver"), strDriver);

    return strDriver;
}
```

If you know which driver you want to use, the just use that. Then open your database:

```
// Opens the database (gets closed in destructor)
void CPTSDatabase::OpenDatabase(bool bAccDbMode, CString strPassword)
{
    CString     strDBConnectString;
    CString     strDriver;

    if (m_dbDatabase.IsOpen())
        return;

    if (DatabaseExist(m_strDatabasePath))
    {
        // AJT v10.5.0 Take into account the DB mode
        strDriver = GetJETDriver(bAccDbMode);
        // Take into account the DB password (decrypted!)
        strDBConnectString.Format(_T("Driver={%s};DBQ=%s;Pwd=%s"),
            strDriver, m_strDatabasePath,
            CPTSTools::DecryptDatabasePassword(strPassword));

        m_dbDatabase.OpenEx(strDBConnectString, CDatabase::noOdbcDialog);
    }
}
```

But a word of **warning** .... And I use my own computer as an example ....

My computer is Windows 10 64 bit ...

It has:

- a **64** bit **ACCDB** Microsoft Database driver
- a **32** bit **MDB** Microsoft Database driver

There is no 64 bit MDB driver. So if you want to work with MDB databases make sure you build your application in 32 bit mode.

Comment: This was helpful, thanks. With some trial and error, I was able to getting working on my Windows 10 machine. Will need some tests to confirm the client also has these drivers. The app is older and was already 32-bit, so I guess I'll keep it there.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to read MS Access .mdb files is **MDAC** (Microsoft Data Access Components) installed on target PC/server.
All modern OSs like Vista/Windows 7/8/8.1/10 have this component pre-installed for your convinience. If you have to target XP you can download this component from MS site. Also the InstallShield comes with MDAC 2.7 merge module if you need to build installer for your app.

You can simply use the standard set of MFC classes to work with databases:

```
CDatabase database;
CString sDsn;
CString sFile = _T("D:\\Projects\\DB\\Test.mdb");

// Build ODBC connection string
sDsn.Format(_T("ODBC;DRIVER={%s};DSN='';DBQ=%s"), _T("MICROSOFT ACCESS DRIVER (*.mdb)"), sFile);
try
{
    // Open the database
    database.Open(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, sDsn);

    // Allocate the recordset
    CRecordset recset( &database );

    // Build the SQL statement
    CString sSqlString =  _T("SELECT Field1, Field2 from MyTable");

    // Execute the query
    recset.Open(CRecordset::forwardOnly, sSqlString, CRecordset::readOnly);

    // Loop through each record
    while( !recset.IsEOF() )
    {
        // Copy each column into a variable
        CString sField1;
        CString sField2;
        recset.GetFieldValue(_T("Field1"), sField1);
        recset.GetFieldValue(_T("Field2"), sField2);

        // goto next record
        recset.MoveNext();
    }
    // Close the database
    database.Close();
}
catch(CDBException* e)
{
    // If a database exception occured, show error msg
    AfxMessageBox(_T("Database error: ") + e->m_strError);
}
```

Comment: To get this running in a Visual Studio 2019 C++ console application, I had to set _Project Properties > Configuration Properties > Advanced > Use of MFC_ to **Use MFC in a Shared DLL**. Additionally I had to `#include <afxdb.h>` (for CDatabase) and `#include <atlstr.h>` (for CString).